# moment.js compare not working as expected

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, datetime-format

I need to compare two dates to check if the selected date is less than today.

```js
//taking current time

    var orignalDateFromAPI = moment();
    var selectedDate = moment(orignalDateFromAPI,"YYYY-MM-DD");

    console.log(selectedDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));

    var nativeDate = new Date(selectedDate);
    var parsedDate= moment(nativeDate,"YYYY-MM-DD");

    console.log(parsedDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));

    console.log(selectedDate.isSame(parsedDate)); //true
    console.log(selectedDate == parsedDate); //false
```

Why does the first statement prints `true` while the second prints `false`?
Is there a better way to check if a date is **less than or equal** to the other date?

EDIT: I went to the question that was marked as a duplicate but couldn't find any answer related to the moment.js comparison.
I went through moment.js docs and found [is same or before](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/). I think this will work fine. Any caveats?

Comment: You can use; `momentObj.isBefore()` or `momentObj.isAfter()`

Comment: You can compare the timestamps directly; objects are only compared by reference in JS. For `less than or equal`, `!isAfter` should suffice.

Comment: I don't think this question is duplicate because the OP asks for why he cannot use `==`. And not why object can't be compared

Answer (score 0):

`==` or `===` cannot be used to compare the `object` type variables. If you see the type of `selectedDate` and `parsedDate` it is of type `object` (of Moment). So, you cannot use `==`. Instead, you must need to use `isSame` function of MomentJS.

```js
var orignalDateFromAPI = moment();
var selectedDate = moment(orignalDateFromAPI,"YYYY-MM-DD");

console.log(selectedDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));

var nativeDate = new Date(selectedDate);
var parsedDate= moment(nativeDate,"YYYY-MM-DD");

console.log(parsedDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));

console.log('typeof selectedDate ' + typeof selectedDate);
console.log(selectedDate.isSame(parsedDate)); //true
console.log(selectedDate == parsedDate); //false
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```